# Dynamic SQL- slow string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a dynamic sql query which loops over all tables in a large dB  (1600 tables) and creates the query I need to run afterwards. After the string is created i save the string and run it. However the string  concatenation is extremely slow . I need to add a lot more boilerplate code for each table but in the example below I've omitted the boilerplate code to keep it simple.

My question is how can I speed up this process of building queries via concatenation of NVARCHAR?  When I run this  query it gets significantly slower the more text and parameter concatenations are added. It takes over 30 mins currently but the CTE executes in 1 sec.

```
DECLARE @UpdateColumnsSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH TableColumns AS
  (
    SELECT
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + 
        '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) AS TableName
     ,LOWER(c.name) AS ColumnName
     ,ty.name AS TypeName
     ,c.max_length AS ColLength
    FROM
      sys.tables AS t
      INNER JOIN
        sys.columns AS c
          ON
          t.object_id = c.object_id
      INNER JOIN
        sys.types AS ty
          ON
          c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE
      c.name IN
        ( 'Company_ID', 'Facility_ID', 'Premises_ID' )
  )
SELECT
  @UpdateColumnsSql = @UpdateColumnsSql + 

  'ALTER TABLE ' + TableColumns.TableName + 
  ' ADD [' + TableColumns.ColumnName + '_New] ' + TypeName + 
   '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), ColLength) + ')' + ' NULL

SET @sql = 
'''' UPDATE T 
       SET T.[' + TableColumns.ColumnName + '_New] = S.[NewValue] 
       from ' + TableColumns.TableName + ' T 
       inner join NewIDList S 
         on Company = Company_ID 
       where T.[' + TableColumns.ColumnName + '] = S.OldValue 
         AND S.[OldColumnName] = ''''''''' + TableColumns.ColumnName + ''''''''' ''''

exec(@sql);
'
FROM
  TableColumns;
```

Comment: Some formatting would help considerably here. But what part is slow? The execution I would imagine could take a LONG time with 1600 tables. But the query to generate the sql should be really fast.

Comment: The query that generates the sql is the slow part. So for each table in the CTE, another string is appended and the ColumnName parameter is replaced with the respective value. This is the slow part . And the more parameters used to build the sql, the slower it gets.

Comment: If you have a ton of data there really isn't anything you can do to make this faster. Perhaps a different approach instead. Maybe instead of building up a big massive string you instead insert each row into a table. Then since this is clearly a one time thing, just create a cursor and iterate over those rows executing the stored sql.

Comment: Let's say you have a string that is 100,000 characters, 200,000 bytes. You append a string of 12 characters. It has to allocate 200,024 bytes, copy 200,000 bytes to the new memory, and copy 24 more bytes. Now add another string of 12 characters, ... and so on.   With each iteration you do this 20 times.  What if you could first concatenate these 20 strings, and then append them once?

Comment: The string that you're generating seems to be a series of ALTER TABLE statements.  Why not convert the CTE into a query where each row returned is one of these single statements, and write the result to a text file?  Then just open up that text file and all your SQL will be ready and waiting.  No concatenation needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.    yes I can reduce the number of times this is needed by running once and saving the generated queries to a table where I can use again.